# How to check in Perl whether there is any sub folder exist in a folder?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to check whether there is any subfolder exist inside a folder. I would like to do this in Perl?

Comment: _any_ subfolders, or one specifically named one?

Comment: any subfolders, not any specific one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the'File::Find' module for this purpose. File::Find processes and scans a directory recursively. Here is the sample code:

```
use File::Find;
my $DirName = 'dirname' ;

sub has_subdir 
{
    #The path of the file/dir being visited.
    my $subdir = $File::Find::name;

    #Ignore if this is a file.
    return unless -d $subdir;

    #Ignore if $subdir is $Dirname itself.
    return if ( $subdir eq $DirName);

    # if we have reached here, this is a subdirector.
    print "Sub directory found - $subdir\n";
}

#For each file and sub directory in $Dirname, 'find' calls 
#the 'has_subdir' subroutine recursively.
find (\&has_subdir, $DirName);
```

Comment: super, this is what exactly i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Glob through the contents of the directory, and check whether it is a directory with `-d`.

```
sub has_subfolder {
  my $directory = shift;
  for ( <$directory/*>, <$directory/.*> ) {
    next if m@/\.\.?$@; # skip . and ..
    return 1 if -d;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe glob will find hidden directories

Comment: This is however probably inefficient on large directories - will most likely result in traversing the directory twice.

Comment: Alnitak: That could easily be solved by making the glob `<$dir/* $dir/.*>` if efficiency is a problem, but I think this is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (grep -d, glob("$folder/*")) {
    print "$folder has subfolder(s)\n";
}
```

If you want to deal with directories matching `.*`, you could do:

```
if (grep -d && !/\.\.?$/, glob("$folder/.* $folder/*")) {
    print "$folder has subfolder(s)\n";
}
```

Comment: I never think to use `glob`. Good answer. (+1)

Comment: I don't believe glob will find hidden directories

Comment: @User: The if condition is an array containing those names.

Comment: @User1111 that wasn't in the requirements, dammit!

Comment: sorry it was mistake I forgot to mention this in the question. Do think it is possible to print the subfolder names?

Comment: yes, see my answer for two routines, one for your original question (doe a folder exit) and another for the real question (what are they called)

Answer (score 1):

```
sub hasSubDir {
    my $dir_name = shift;
    opendir my $dir, $dir_name
      or die "Could not open directory $dir_name: $!";
    my @files = readdir($dir);
    closedir($dir);
    for my $file (@files) {
       if($file !~ /\.\.?$/) {
           return 1 if -d $dir/$file;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: still a -1 - you didn't closedir() before the early exit

Comment: You don't have to close lexical handles manually. closing happens automatically as soon as the last reference to the handle goes away

Comment: @planetp - I didn't know that.  IMHO still good practise to cleanup nicely.  Someone might port the code to another language which doesn't do it for them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if a subfolder exists in a directory (without knowing any names):

```
my $dir_name = "some_directory";
opendir my $dir, $dir_name
    or die "Could not open directory $dir_name: $!";

my $has_subfolder = grep { -d && !/(^|\/)\.\.?$/ } map { ("$dir_name"||'.')."/$_" } readdir $dir;
```

In other words, it checks for one or more files in the directory which are themselves directories.

If you want a specific subfolder, just use Geo's answer.

**Edit:** This is getting silly now, but here's a truly general-purpose answer. :-P Someone else is getting the check mark anyway.

Comment: will this filter out '.' and '..' ?

Comment: don't forget to prepend the directory before the '-d' test, too!

Comment: @Alnitak: Geez, I'm slipping today.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm just gonna have to submit my own answer

```
sub has_subfolder {
  my $dir = shift;
  my $found = 0;
  opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Could not open directory $dir: $!";
  while (my $_ = readdir($dh)) {
    next if (/^\.\.?$/);        # skip '.' and '..'
    my $path = $dir . '/' . $_; # readdir doesn't return the whole path
    if (-d $path) {             # found a dir?  record it, and leave the loop!   
      $found = 1;
      last;    
  }
  closedir($dh);                # make sure we cleanup after!
  return $found;
}
```

Compared to other answers:

- finds hidden directories
- completes as soon as it finds a match
- doesn't traverse the tree twice (once for normal files, and again for hidden files)

**EDIT** - I see the requirements just changed (sigh).  Fortunately the code above is trivially modified:

```
sub get_folders {
  my $dir = shift;
  my @found;
  opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Could not open directory $dir: $!";
  while (my $_ = readdir($dh)) {
    next if (/^\.\.?$/);           # skip '.' and '..'
    my $path = $dir . '/' . $_;    # readdir doesn't return the whole path
    push(@found, $_) if (-d $path) # found a dir? record it 
  }
  closedir($dh);                   # make sure we cleanup after!
  return @found;
}
```

Comment: next if if? (It was a quick fix, hope you don't mind my editing it.) +1 for being a good sport.

Comment: All of those points apply to my answer too. You could mention that yours doesn't interpolate glob special characters, though.

Comment: two of the three didn't apply in your original answer

Comment: **NEVER** assign to `$_` without localizing  the variable.  Place `local $_;` before each `while` loop, or better yet `local *_;` which protects against tied values.  Or just write `for (readdir $dh) {...}` and let perl do all of that for you.

Comment: @Eric I did originally just have `while (readdir $dh)` but it didn't autoassign to `$_`.  I did forget to localise it, though.

Comment: @Alnitak => It's easy to forget, and causes endless headaches when you do.  The worst offender is the implicit assignment with `readline`, since that's code you don't usually see.  I don't know if it made it in yet, but I believe that making `readdir` behave like `readline` in a while loop is suggested for addition to new perl versions.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(-e "some_folder/some_subfolder") {
   print "folder exists";
}
else {
   print "folder does not exist";
}
```

Comment: `-e` checks if a file or dir exists, not only a directory